# Xamarin UWP “Access to the path is denied” when trying to read a file

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am trying to ReadAllBytes of a pdf file using Xamarin.UWP which is in C: drive. For this I have given broadFileSystemAccess like

```
<Package
  ...
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp uap5 rescap">
...
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
</Capabilities>
```

And my code for reading all bytes like

```
string pdfFilePath = @"C:\Users\...\Documents\TestPDF.pdf";
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pdfFilePath);
```

but it is showing “Access to the path  is denied". Any one please help how to read bytes.

Comment: You will still need to use the Windows.Storage API to access those files. System.IO is not aware of the capability.

Comment: An UWP app is sandbox, you don't have to access to the C:\ or any other drive. By accessing storage path; var filepath = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;

Comment: @Prasanth the app does have access with the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability (if the user enables it), but as @Cheesebaron says (nice name btw :)), `System.IO` doesn't yet work.